# Pig: how to split array

Tags: apache-pig

i have a tuple like this:

```
((item114,),1)
((item32,item31,),1)
((item81,item27,),2)
```

the last number is the frequency of the item,so item114 has freq. of 1, item 81 has freq. of 2, now i want to split it to tuple of the format: (item#, freq.), so the result would be:

```
 (item114, 1)
 (item32, 1)
 (item31, 1)
 (item81, 2)
 (item27, 2)
```

how can i do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could essentially flatten out the relation, which shall give you the desired tuple.
For example, let C describe the above relation which is as follows,

```
C = GROUP input by A;

describe C;
C: {group: int, input: {i: int,j: int,k: int}}

dump C;
({(item114,)},1)

d = foreach c generate group, flatten(a.i);

describe d;
d: {group: int,i::i: int}

dump d;
(item114, 1)
(item32, 1)
```

Comment: @phonix24: in your example, what's input and what's A?